# Opening a URL files (.pdf) in Safari from UIWebView

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, pdf, uiwebview

I need my app to recognize the `.PDF` extension, and open it in Safari instead of my `UIWebView`, but if i called a domain such as http://google.com, i want it to open it in the `UIWebView`.

Please Advice

Comment: Thanks Mutawe, for the translation. the english is not my first (or whatever) lenguaje.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the MIME type too, for a slightly longer journey:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *mime;

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response 
{
   mime = [response MIMEType];
}

- (BOOL)isDisplayingPDF {
    NSString *extension = [[mime substringFromIndex:([mime length] - 3)] lowercaseString];

    return ([[[self.webView.request.URL pathExtension] lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"pdf"] || [extension isEqualToString:@"pdf"]);
}
```

You should use the following Opening a URL files (.pdf)  :

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.stackoverflow.com/dd.pdf"];

if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url])

NSLog(@"%@%@",@"Failed to open url:",[url description]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will open in safari without using webview

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
if (url != nil && [url isFileURL]) {
    if ([[url pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"pdf"]) {
        NSLog(@"URL:%@", [url absoluteString]);
    }
}
return YES;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"your pdf url"];

if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url])
    NSLog(@"%@%@",@" open url:",[url description]);
}
```